# Programmatically removing sublayouts in Sitecore

Tags: c#, .net, sitecore, sitecore6

Does anyone know how to remove the renderings from a Sitecore item?

I want to remove all of the sublayouts so I can replace them with a new set. 
I have [tried this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8287624/sitecore-programmatically-add-layout-value-cannot-not-be-null-parameter-name-p) but it does not seem to work. Nothing changes on the item.

I appear to be able to get the renderings like this:

```
RenderingReference[] renderings = item.Visualization.GetRenderings(Sitecore.Context.Device, true);
```

But there appears to be no way to then set them.

I can also get the renderings like this (from the link above):

```
LayoutDefinition layoutDefinition = LayoutDefinition.Parse(LayoutField.GetFieldValue(item.Fields[Sitecore.FieldIDs.LayoutField]));
DeviceDefinition device = layoutDefinition.GetDevice(Sitecore.Context.Device.ID.ToString());

if (device.Layout != null) device.Layout = null;
if (device.Renderings != null) device.Renderings = new ArrayList();
```

But again this does not work. Clearing the device from the layoutDefinition and setting the modified one has led to this exception: `No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it`. And I now cannot view the item at all!

I feel like I'm barking up the wrong tree, any ideas?

*Using Sitecore 6.4*

**UPDATE Re: techphoria414**

Code I tried:

```
layoutDefinition.Devices.Clear();
layoutDefinition.Devices.Add(device);
```

Comment: Can you provide the code you are using to save the changes back to the field, and the full stack trace of the exception?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think your exception is unrelated. To actually save your changes, you need to edit the item.  Be sure you always access and update the value throgh `LayoutField.Value`.

```
LayoutField layoutField = new LayoutField(item.Fields[Sitecore.FieldIDs.LayoutField]);
LayoutDefinition layout = LayoutDefinition.Parse(layoutField.Value);
//make your changes to the LayoutDefinition here
item.Editing.BeginEdit();
layoutField.Value = layout.ToXml();
item.Editing.EndEdit();
```

Comment: Doesn't he want to remove the sublayouts though, not add a layout?

Comment: Still applies, you can make whatever changes you like to the LayoutDefinition, which includes information on the layout and renderings for each device.

Comment: Ahhh, I didn't realize the `LayoutDefinition` contains the details about the renderings. That's very good to know!