# Temporarily change a Sitecore item's layout

Tags: c#, .net, sitecore, sitecore6

Using this code I managed to change the renderings on the current item. However this changed it permenantly in Sitecore (the changes were could be seen in the CMS) and not temporarily, as I expected.

```
void ReplaceLayout(Item item)
{
    if (item == null)
        return;

    using (new SecurityDisabler())
    {
        // New item
        LayoutField newLayoutField = new LayoutField(item.Fields[Sitecore.FieldIDs.LayoutField]);
        LayoutDefinition newLayoutDefinition = LayoutDefinition.Parse(newLayoutField.Value);

        DeviceDefinition newDeviceDefinition = newLayoutDefinition.GetDevice(Sitecore.Context.Device.ID.ToString());

        // Current item
        LayoutField layoutField = new LayoutField(Sitecore.Context.Item.Fields[Sitecore.FieldIDs.LayoutField]);
        LayoutDefinition layoutDefinition = LayoutDefinition.Parse(layoutField.Value);

        DeviceDefinition deviceDefinition = layoutDefinition.GetDevice(Sitecore.Context.Device.ID.ToString());
        deviceDefinition.Layout = newDeviceDefinition.Layout;
        deviceDefinition.Renderings = newDeviceDefinition.Renderings;

        Sitecore.Context.Item.Editing.BeginEdit();
        layoutField.Value = layoutDefinition.ToXml();
        Sitecore.Context.Item.Editing.EndEdit();
    }
}
```

I don't want to make permenant changes to the item, I just want to replace the currently displayed items renderings on the fly if some conditions are met. Does anyone know how to alter an item's layout in this way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You explained in your comments that you want to display certain sublayouts in the sidebar depending on certain form parts/steps.
You can do that by adding a PlaceHolder that will fit the sublayouts (e.g. in your sidebar) and use this code to dynamically render sublayouts to it.

First you need an item (i call it a snippet item) that has the sublayout configured on its presentation settings.
Then you can use code to render that item inside the placeholder (phSideBarPlaceHolder).

```
// Load snippet item
Item snippet = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem("{id-or-path-of-snippet-item}");

// Get the first rendering from item's presentation definition
RenderingReference rendering = snippet.Visualization.GetRenderings(Sitecore.Context.Device, false).FirstOrDefault();

// We assume that its a Sublayout, but you can also check for xslt and create an XslFile() object
Sublayout sublayout = new Sublayout();
sublayout.DataSource = snippet.Paths.FullPath; // creates a reference to the snippet item, so you can pull data from that later on
sublayout.Path = rendering.RenderingItem.InnerItem["Path"];
sublayout.Cacheable = rendering.RenderingItem.Caching.Cacheable;

// Copy cache settings
if (rendering.RenderingItem.Caching.Cacheable)
{
    sublayout.VaryByData = rendering.RenderingItem.Caching.VaryByData;
    sublayout.VaryByDevice = rendering.RenderingItem.Caching.VaryByDevice;
    sublayout.VaryByLogin = rendering.RenderingItem.Caching.VaryByLogin;
    sublayout.VaryByParm = rendering.RenderingItem.Caching.VaryByParm;
    sublayout.VaryByQueryString = rendering.RenderingItem.Caching.VaryByQueryString;
    sublayout.VaryByUser = rendering.RenderingItem.Caching.VaryByUser;
}

// Now render the sublayout to the placeholder
phSideBarPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(sublayout);
```

If you need more info about how to read data the DataSource property inside the sublayout code, Mark Ursino has written an article about that: http://firebreaksice.com/using-the-datasource-field-with-sitecore-sublayouts

Comment: This works nicely, however is there any way to remove the need for the snippet item? Or is there a way to grab all of the renderings from an item including their placeholders without the need for a dummy subitem with the PlaceHolder control. In essence to say okay, I don't want to use the parent layout for this part/step, I want to use the layout for the child instead. Or are we into the realms of what @techphoria414 is talking about above?

Comment: I think you can just load the Sublayout item (with Database.GetItem) and then construct a RenderingItem object based on that item:

var renderingItem = new Sitecore.Data.Items.RenderingItem(sublayoutItem);

I have not tested this though.
Hope that helps.

Comment: I added `sublayout.Parameters = rendering.Settings.Parameters;` in order to get hold of the rendering parameters. Aside from that this was the solution I went with in the end.

Answer (score 2):

Sitecore constructs the rendering controls and inserts them into the page very early in the ASP.NET Webforms lifecycle. It's not likely you can easily do this on the layout itself. However, if you can evaluate your conditions outside the page (e.g. by examining the item itself), you can probably do this in the `insertRenderings` pipeline.

Use ILSpy or another decompiler to check out `Sitecore.Pipelines.InsertRenderings` and `Sitecore.Pipelines.InsertRenderings.Processors`. As with other pipelines, the order of execution of these processors is defined in Web.config. You will want to add a new processor after AddRenderings which evaluates your conditions (likely examining `args.ContextItem`) and then modifies `args.Renderings` as needed.

In your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9604819/programatically-removing-sublayouts-in-sitecore/9605660#9605660) you were just looking to remove sublayouts. That should be fairly easy here. Adding different sublayouts is more difficult since you would need to construct a `RenderingReference`. This may require that you actually create the XML definition needed for its constructor. Or, if you have another item that defines the desired new layout, consider just changing `args.ContextItem` earlier in the pipeline.

Comment: Sadly I cannot evaluate my conditions until much later, it relies on a database call. I was hoping I could add a sublayout at that point but if I'm reading your answer correctly this is not possible?

Comment: Can you provide more detail on that logic and database call? It may be possible. Otherwise, you may need to modify the ASP.NET control tree yourself, perhaps in the Page OnInit, rather than depending on Sitecore's rendering.

Comment: We have a form which has different parts to it, and then each part has different steps. The database call happens during a sublayout's Init. This then determines which part of the form we load in. These are represented by child items to our form item. What we want to do is to display certain sublayouts in our sidebar on certain parts/steps. This requires a database call as the form does not necessarily execute sequentially. We were hoping to work out which part/step we were on and simply drop in a sublayout at that point. Hope that made some sort of sense!

Comment: This sounds like a good use of Conditional Renderings. Not sure how you're maintaining state for the forms, but you may be able to create some custom rendering conditions that you can place on the rendering references.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than change sitecore presentation, can you not place the 'form' control and sidebar within one parent control container? You would then have an an easy id for a sidebar container with which to conditionally populate controls programatically from the form control.

Alternatively, could you add all the possible controls to the sidebar and 'activate' (or perhaps just make visible) the required control(s), maybe via session state variables? (I dont know if this falls foul of some lifecycle or timing limitiation)

Comment: Sadly it needs to run through the Sitecore system as the sublayouts I'm wanting to render have rendering parameters that I need! There's also the caveat that they may be used elsewhere on the site, outside of this system so they need to be standalone too!

Comment: Hmmm... Both of these options can be used in conjunction with standard sitecore presentation settings. ?

Answer (score 0):

Or you can simply use conditional rendering rules to display the renderings/sublayouts you want based on whatever logic you can dream up.