# Setting the Path attribute of a sublayout in codebehind doesn't work

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I have a sublayout that I want to statically bind  in a few different layouts. As such, I don't want to declaratively specify the path attribute in the designer on every instance of sublayout. What I really want to do is have a constants file (or config file) that contains the paths to by sublayouts, which I then use set the path f the given sublayout  in the code behind files of the containing sublayouts.

However, when I try to set the path attribute in either `on_load` or `on_init`, the sublayout does not get rendered to the page.  Am I missing something?

Example:

```
private void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   plBakingTips.Path = "/layouts/User Defined/Sublayouts/Products/Product List/Product/Product Bake It Yours.ascx";
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to as you say statically (I think you mean dynamically) add a layout fro mthe code behind? What are the reasons moving you to a solution like this? Sitecore can do this for you.

Answer (score 1):

Sitecore by default sets up all page controls in PreInit. You can change this, but it is a global setting and I'm not sure I'd recommend changing it.

However there is a "factory" you can override that constructs the sublayouts, which might allow you to do this. Implement a custom SublayoutRenderingType and override Sitecore's default in web.config.

See an example here:
http://sitecoreblog.alexshyba.com/2011/08/sitecore-output-caching-kick-it-up.html?m=1

Answer (score 1):

Try to prefix the path with a ~

```
Path = "~/layouts...";
```

Also, that's a file system path, not sublayout item path (I mention this because your path looks like an item path)

Answer (score 0):

This should be exactly what you need. It allows you to add a sub layout in the code behind

[Temporarily change a Sitecore item's layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9666805/temporarily-change-a-sitecore-items-layout)

I've used to change the data source of sub layouts and it works well.

Comment: I think that this is not an answer to this question. Also changing the datasource of a sublayout is something completely different from temporarely changing a layout...

Comment: Changing the data source is one example of things you can do with this approach. The main thing the answer explains is to change / insert a layout in the code, which is (I think) what the user is asking...