# Issue trying to use Datasource Template in Sitecore sublayout; getting empty Sublayout.Datasource

Tags: sitecore

We've been trying to "componentize" our Sitecore solution as we move forward, in prep for transitioning to Page Editor usage (Woot! Finally!), but we're still practically working primarily with Page templates that may be inheritance-based composites of page specific fields, plus 1:many of these componentized templates. An example of how this looks in our solution is below -- Banner Feature Carousel and Featured Cartoon are some of these new components we're creating:

[image: Base templates showing components]

In the interest of trying to move away from using Sitecore.Context.Item (as I was recently reminded by [this post](http://intothecore.cassidy.dk/2013/08/the-page-template-mistake.html)) I've started filling in the Datasource template field on the sublayouts for the new components, and it seems like I've got the appropriate connections made between presentation details, the Sitecore sublayout and the .NET code file (as far as I can tell; again, we're newer to working this way).

I've also tried setting up a base class for these components as per [this post by Nick Allen](http://www.sitecore.net/belgie/Community/Best-Practice-Blogs/Nick-Allen/Posts/2012/03/Introduction-to-Sitecore-Parameter-Templates.aspx), but here's where I'm running into a problem: When I execute my code, this base class is finding the component Sublayout appropriately (the whole "this.Parent as Sublayout" thing) but, when I go to interrogate the Sublayout.Datasource property, it's an empty string. Here's my code (so far) for this base class:

```
public class ComponentBase : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    private Sublayout Sublayout { get { return Parent as Sublayout; } }

    public Item DataSourceItem 
    { 
        get 
        { 
            return Sublayout != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Sublayout.DataSource) ? 
            Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(Sublayout.DataSource) : Sitecore.Context.Item; 
        } 
    }
}
```

I'm apparently missing some interplay between the Datasource Template field in the Sitecore sublayout, and how that actually translates to a datasource. Is it because these component templates are being used to compose Page templates? I was thinking that the datasource would just ultimately resolve to the Page template on which the component in question was currently being used, but perhaps that's my misunderstanding.

If anyone could give me any hints of things to check or point me to any resources I might use to get further, I'd appreciate it. I've done quite a bit of asking the Googs, myself, but am just not getting anything that's helping.

Thank you in advance, Sitecore friends!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have configured the allowed templates for your sublayout in the steps you describe above.  This basically tells Sitecore; 'allow user to select items based on these templates for this sublayout'.  This alone does not set up the data source on items using the sublayout.  You still need to go into the presentation details for any items using this sublayout, select the sublayout and then set its datasource property (within the content editor go to **Presentation > Details > [Sublayout] > Data Source**).

My [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17835166/render-child-items-with-their-own-layout-in-a-carousel-control/17836887#17836887) gives the source code needed to retrieve the datasource item and to iterate through the sitecore controls on your sublayout setting all of their `Item` propertys.

**Here is the code:**

```
public class SublayoutBase : UserControl
{
    private Item _dataSource;

    public Item DataSource
    {
        get
        {
            if (_dataSource == null)
            {
                if (Parent is Sublayout)
                {
                    _dataSource =
                        Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(((Sublayout)Parent).DataSource);
                }
                if (_dataSource == null)
                {
                    _dataSource = Sitecore.Context.Item;
                }
            }
            return _dataSource;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Control c in Controls)
        {
            SetFieldRenderers(DataSource, c);
        }
        base.OnLoad(e);
    }

    private void SetFieldRenderers(Item item, Control control)
    {
        if (item != null)
        {
            var ctrl = control as Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControl;
            if (ctrl != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(ctrl.DataSource))
            {
                //don't set the source item if the DataSource has already been set. 
                return;
            }
            if (control is FieldRenderer)
            {
                var fr = (FieldRenderer)control;
                fr.Item = item;
            }
            else if (control is Image)
            {
                var img = (Image)control;
                img.Item = item;
            }
            else if (control is Link)
            {
                var link = (Link)control;
                link.Item = item;
            }
            else if (control is Text)
            {
                var text = (Text)control;
                text.Item = item;
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (Control childControl in control.Controls)
                {
                    SetFieldRenderers(item, childControl);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but the Datasource retrieval code you included here looks like the same thing I was doing -- my problem is that the datasource is coming back as an empty string, even when I've set the Datasource Template in the sublayout in Sitecore. If I can get a datasource returned, your code looks like it'd be very useful!

Comment: Setting the datasource template on the sublayout definition item (the item under `/sitecore/layout/Sublayouts`) will just define what types of item you can select for the datasource.  You will still need to set the DataSource on the sublayout for the given content item (within the presentation details of your content item).

Comment: mdresser has it right. Setting the Datasource is something you do as you add the component to the presentation details - not something you do statically at the sublayout definition level

Comment: Thanks Mark and mdresser -- this was the clarification I needed!

Comment: @mdresser, A follow up question to this -- I never did get this working (abandoned it in favor of another temporary option), but I'm trying to circle back to it. The issue I have now is that, for a certain sublayout, I'm finding I'm not able to cast the parent as a sublayout, even though it definitely is one. My code is doing exactly what yours is above, but I'm just getting null when I try to do the cast. Any ideas as to why that might be?

Comment: If the above code is not working, you could check the following
1) ensure that your sublayout really is included on the page in question and it's in a valid placeholder 
2) check that the sublayout item (under sitecore/layout/Sublayouts...) is 
a) using the template /sitecore/templates/System/Layout/Renderings/Sublayout and 
b) has it's 'Ascx File' field set to the correct ascx from your solution 
3) everything from your solution (ascx and dlls) has been correctly pushed across to the webroot directory.

Comment: Thanks, @mdresser, I had an issue with my placeholder that I just didn't see when I had looked at the code before. :) Appreciate the tips!

Answer (score 0):

When you start using sublayouts on which you will set your datasource try to use the marketplace "Sublayout Parameter Helper". When you use the class they provide as base class and have set everything up right in your Sitecore Environment you will find yourself having a "this.DatasourceItem" -> which will contain your datasource Item, or the context Item if none is given.

http://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Sub_Layout_Parameter_Helper.aspx

To find out more on how datasource works, try searching on http://sdn.sitecore.net. There is alot of documentation available that should get you in the right direction. Generally it will be enough to just add a datasource in the sublayout that you can access in your sublayout.

When you read a datasource from a sublayout all it will do is check if the datasource field on that sublayout is filled and will return you information regarding this datasource. So when you add a new component to a page using the page editor (for example a sublayout for a news article) and you have a datasource template defined and filled in during adding this components, you will see that when you check the presentation details on that page a sublyaout with a datasource has been added. The datasource will point to a folder in which you will find an item based on the datasource template you specified on your sublayout. You should also double check this, cause if no datasource is present on the added sublayout it will be obvious you can't access it from your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Sitecore 7 update 1 you can actually now use the attributes. From the Release Notes:

> To make it easier to get the data source for a sublayout from
>   code-behind, the data source is now transferred to the sublayout
>   control in a "sc_datasource" attribute. (320768)
>
> To get the data source from code, simply refer to
>   this.Attributes["sc_datasource"];

Comment: Thanks, but we are not on Sitecore 7 yet (I should have mentioned that in my note); we'll hopefully be upgrading in the next 3-6 months. We're on 6.4 currently.