# Remove Rendering from Sitecore Item

Tags: sitecore, rendering, removeall

I have  to remove all instance of a rendering by rendering id. I tried below code but its not working.

```cs
LayoutField layoutField = new LayoutField(item.Fields[Sitecore.FieldIDs.LayoutField]);
LayoutDefinition layoutDefinition = LayoutDefinition.Parse(layoutField.Value);
DeviceDefinition deviceDefinition = layoutDefinition.GetDevice(Sitecore.Context.Device.ID.ToString());

//Create a RenderingDefinition and add the reference of sublayout or rendering
RenderingDefinition renderingDefinition = new RenderingDefinition();
renderingDefinition.ItemID = sublayoutId;

var d = layoutDefinition.GetDevice(deviceDefinition.ID.ToString());
d.Renderings.Remove(renderingDefinition);

item.Editing.BeginEdit();
layoutField.Value = layoutDefinition.ToXml();
item.Editing.EndEdit();
```

I have referred:

- http://blog.ryanbailey.co.nz/2016/08/sitecore-remove-renderings-or.html
- [Programmatically removing sublayouts in Sitecore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9604819/programmatically-removing-sublayouts-in-sitecore)

Comment: At what moment are you removing the rendering? Is it a one off execution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try code below. I haven't tested it but instead of creating a `RenderingDefinition` object and removing it from the list (which won't work cause it's not the same instance of the object), it filters the existing array of renderings comparing `ItemId` property:

```cs
LayoutField layoutField = new LayoutField(item.Fields[Sitecore.FieldIDs.LayoutField]);
LayoutDefinition layoutDefinition = LayoutDefinition.Parse(layoutField.Value);
DeviceDefinition deviceDefinition = layoutDefinition.GetDevice(Sitecore.Context.Device.ID.ToString());

var d = layoutDefinition.GetDevice(deviceDefinition.ID.ToString());

IEnumerable<RenderingDefinition> renderingsArray = d.Renderings.ToArray().Cast<RenderingDefinition>();
d.Renderings = new ArrayList(renderingsArray.Where(r => r.ItemID != sublayoutId).ToList());

item.Editing.BeginEdit();
layoutField.Value = layoutDefinition.ToXml();
item.Editing.EndEdit();
```

Comment: Getting error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Sitecore.Layouts.RenderingDefinition>' to 'int'"    in line # 6

Comment: I've updated the answer to use `IEnumerable<Sitecore.Layouts.Ren‌​deringDefinition>` explicitly instead of using `var`. Try now.